# ENTITY FRAMEWORK - add-migration Novo Projeto sem renomear tabelas do antigo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-4

Quero compartilhar um banco de dados com alguns projetos.

Já fiz o primeiro projeto com o banco e está ok.
Copiei o projeto para criar outro similar, alterei o prefixo inicial das tabelas Ex: projeto1_cliente, projeto2_cliente e ai que está acontecendo o problema.
Ao gerar o add-migration no novo projeto ele está sugerindo renomear as tabelas do projeto antigo.

**Como posso trabalhar distintamente o add-migration nos projetos?**

Comment: Como foi feita essa prefixação?

Answer (score 0):

Use um [TableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) `[Table("NomeTabela")]`

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("NomeTabela")]
public class NomeClasse
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Ele é responsável por mapear sua entidade para a tabela com o nome especificado.